# Google map features and its cost

Tags: dictionary

We want to make an app where we need to integrate google map. Though we have visited the google web page for knowing the pricing. We want to know If we integrate as it "Standard User" and want to have below feature
As per our understanding - google charges whenever the map is loaded or API is used by the user. Anything above the daily quota of map load has to be paid.

- In Zoom feature - will Zoom in and zoom out is treated as two calls.
- Similarly, pan feature - will it be treated as map load
- Draw circle to create an area on the map  to find specific info which is already fed by the user based on the location. Will it also be treated as a call or map load?
- In case if user to find location with typing - will the number of characters typed and its search result will be treated as API call for which we have to pay in the case of the above daily quota

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the  last two but the first two are covered in the [FAQ for Google Map APIs](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#usage_mapload)

> After a web page or application loads a map, a static map image, or a Street View panorama, any user interactions with it, such as panning, zooming, or switching map layers, do not generate additional map loads or affect usage limits.